# One way Streaming - ICE Connection fails before adding candidates

Tags: javascript, webrtc

**Scenario -**

- A wants to stream his webcam to B
- B just wants to view, and won't share anything
- Basically one way stream from **A => B**

A create's offer and sends it over

**At B's side**

Get an offer from "A"

[Offer removed]

Set it as Remote Description

Signal State changes to SignalingStateHaveRemoteOffer

OnAddStream is called

```
label: PiB7Ij4lDsH9D8SxYIOyYBQcnd0tWWnTALtO, video: [a83c8794-aec4-4077-b06b-d218c8e18e74] is called
```

B Create's Answer (No constraints for now)

On Success is called

This is the anwer (**as no streams exist it's recvonly**)

[Edit:Answer removed]

Set this Answer as local sdp

Signal State changes to SignalingStateStable

ICE Connection becomes ICEConnectionStateChecking

setLocalDescriptionOnSuccess is called

Gathering state becomes ICEGatheringStateGathering

Bunch of onIceCandidate events

ICEGatheringStateComplete

**ICE fails now.**

ICEConnectionState => *ICEConnectionStateFailed*

**I've not even started adding trickled ICE Candidates from A yet**.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does the ICEConnectionState change to failed for A or B?

Comment: No at A's side it remains in checking state after I add back remote description. And at B's side, the state doesn't change after adding A's trickled ICE candidates

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
Even in one-way streaming, both sides need to exchange ICE.

I thought if only A is streaming, it's enough to send ICE's candidates over. But ICE connection will fail if B doesn't send over ice candidates back to A.

Comment: Indeed. ICE is the mechanism with which both sides figure out how to connect to one another. This must be a two-way process, one peer can't just talk into the void here.

Comment: I went with wrong assumption - once B gets ice candidates it can ping A with username/pwd and start to work with whichever it can. Thank you for clarifying. Can you recommend any good resources for learning more about ICE?